# Move a method to another file using phpstorm

Tags: ide, phpstorm

Extract method can be used to extract a method to the same file, but if I want to move the method to another class, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating this for anyone finding this through a search engine...

---

As of PhpStorm 7, moving static members is supported.
You can utilise this feature by right-clicking a static member and choosing `Refactor` > `Move...`.

See also: https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/09/move-static-member-refactoring-for-php-in-phpstorm/